# When viewing website for first time, website formatting messed up. Refresh fixes

Tags: jquery, html, fullpage.js

So I'm having a bit of an issue, I think it is to do with how my files are loading within my header. I'm using the fullpage.js plugin currently.

When I visit the website for the first time (non-cached) it looks wrong. However after a refresh the same messed up formatting starts to load for a second then my pre-loader kicks in and my website works? See image below for what it looks like on initial view. Note its only been developed for Chrome at the moment...

[image: Messed up Formatting - initial view]

What the homepage looks like after refresh on load...

[image]

Here is the website url: http://carrotcrunchpvp.comule.com/ to replicate the issue for yourselves.

In my console, it says :

fullpage_initialisation.js:2
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

The link for this file is: http://carrotcrunchpvp.comule.com/js/fullpage_initialisation.js

However I have followed the formatting on the fullpage.js github and everything seems to work fine. I want the website to just load normally first time without having to refresh and I'm stumped. I've played around with the heads' order and to no avail

Here's the head snippet:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Catholic Professional Standards</title>

  <link href="plugins/fullpage/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="media-queries.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="plugins/fullpage/jquery.fullPage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/fullpage_initialisation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: interesting. it's almost like the full page script isn't fully loaded when you initialize it.

Comment: lol @realseanp. Sorry about that buddy, free hosting has its downsides as a development website. Adblock should do its job

Comment: Yeah it would appear so, either that or I've done some stupid syntaxical error

Comment: @ChrisConnolly - consider looking at Byethost (not a spelling error) then. 1 email, 1gb storage, 5 MySQL databases and a monthly traffic limit of 5gb - all for free. They don't inject any ads into your page. Using SqLite allows as many databases as you like, limited only by the 1gb of disk-space.

Comment: Interesting! I might have a look into them, cheers for the advice!
As per my problem do you have any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Even more interesting, the backend coding with Webhost 000 was screwing with my code. Transferred over to Byethost and issue is resolved... Awesome
New url: http://nops.byethost8.com/

Comment: @ChrisConnolly - a pleasure, you're welcome. Glad to hear you got the problem resolved. By the way, if you put an @ before someone's username in a comment, they get notification of your reply. I just discovered yours when re-visiting out of curiosity. :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with my webhosting company - webhost 000. As I was using a free domain hosting package, they bundles adverts into the website which messed with my code.
Transferring my website to Byethost fixed everything. Plus they don't integrate ads at all. Very impressed with them.

Chris